# Setting different orientations for each screen in Flutter app causes massive lag

Tags: flutter, orientation

I am setting a main menu screen with a portrait orientation which then navigates to a second screen which needs to be landscape orientation.

It feels like these two settings are fighting with each other, and as soon as I set the landscape setting the app goes from instantaneous responses to 2 seconds or screen lag to switch screens.

Code snippets:

```
class MainMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,]);
```

That is how I set my initial orientation.

Navigate to the next screen like so from a button push:

```
Navigator.push(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
);

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,]);
```

My orientation for the second screen.   If I remove the SystemChrome lines it is responsive.   If I add them back in, it lags excessively.

Is there a different method I should be using for sub screens?

Thanks guys.

Edit:

Attempted to implement the theory-based solution from Pete below, which throws piles of:

```
Another exception was thrown: inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_InheritedTheme) or inheritFromElement() was called after dispose():
```

errors in the console (but the app doesn't crash, I just see a split second of a crash dump as the screens navigate back and forth).   Code used:

```
class MainMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainMenuParentState createState() => _MainMenuParentState();
}

class _MainMenuParentState extends State<MainMenu> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,]);
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I have tried in the initState to use Future as well, but the errors each time are identical.

Dispose is called in the onPress:

```
onPressed: () {
    dispose();
    Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
);
```

And I do exactly the same the other way, I have converted SecondScreen to a statefulwidget, used initstate to set as landscape and called dispose exactly the same way.

Comment: The exception you're facing is unrelated to this question

Comment: It isn't really.   The question relates to a problem that has only had one proposed solution, which I do not know how to implement (if I have done it wrong).    So therefore, the exception is valid as the answer does not reliably resolve the issue.   As it is the only one I have been given to go on, I felt this needed pursuing, as I may have just implemented it in the wrong way and I need direction.

Comment: What I mean is, the stacktrace you gave is totally unrelated to `SystemChrome`. It has to do with using `Theme` inside `dispose`.

Comment: Thank for your replies, Remi, I appreciate it.   I don't know what you mean though, in my dispose methods shown above there is nothing related to Theme there.  It's supposed to remove the screen orientation between screens.

Comment: Can you add the entire stacktrace? It's difficult to see where it is coming from as is.

Comment: The error is because of the `Navigator` call after `dispose`. As far as I know, the framework calls `dispose()` for you and you shouldn't be calling it yourself. Usually after you push a route, the old route still exists behind. Maybe unset the orientation in it's own function which you call instead of `dispose`.

Comment: Thanks, Lucas.   This appears to have resolved this error!   I renamed the dispose override to a custom function, and it no longer throws me any exceptions.   Thank you for your assistance.  Post answer as something I an accept and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put any call of `SystemChrome` inside `build()` method. Make your screen extends from `StatefulWidget`. Trigger the `SystemChrome` call inside `initState()` with a `Future`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Pete.   Any chance you could show what this looks like in code?

Comment: I have tried fumbling through this vague solution on my own and it now no longer lags at all, but I get loads of:   "Another exception was thrown: inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_InheritedTheme) or inheritFromElement() was called after dispose():"    - Code usage added to question.